# Send Command to serial port via Cu and exit in same line

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, debian, raspbian

I want to execute "sw i01" into cu command and exit cu (with "~.")

in just one line or in file bash because il will execute them from a distant
server

> [image: cu command]

In this image i put:

```
cu -s 19200 -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

then it return "Connected."

i put "sw i01" (command switch HDMI to input 1)

it return "Command Ok"

then i exit with "~."

(the same for **screen** command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`echo "sw i01" | cu -s 19200 -l /dev/ttyUSB0`

If that won't work, then put `cu -s 19200 -l /dev/ttyUSB0` into a bash script (make it executable `chmod +x script.sh`) and execute it in following way:

`echo "sw i01" | script.sh`